# Network between Windows 7 and XP - how ?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking

Can someone please post a little step-by-step tutorial about how to create a local area connection between my windows 7 laptop and the XP computer - i tried something but it didn't work.

PLEASE don't point me to other questions, just answer it, link me to some nice tutorials you know where the process is explained because i am in a hurry ?
Thank you.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Do you want to share files? or do you want to share an internet connection?

Answer (score 2):

[See this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/share-files-and-printers-between-windows-7-and-xp/)

[Or this one](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/help/home-sweet-homegroup-networking-the-easy-way)

Comment: but I like Mad formatting.